# pytesseract: convert pictures of 7-segment numbers to text

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, text-recognition

I'm trying to convert pictures like this:
7-segment into text with pytesseract:

[image: 7-segment]

I tried different PSM modes and a whitelist with only 0123456789, but the best output of pytesseract was '5' instead of '125'.

Is there a way to configure pytesseract in way that it can convert my pictures? Or are there any extensions?

Thank you.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img = Image.open('test.png')

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=("-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789 --psm 7"))

print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read and follow [docs](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md)
2. Use [letsgodigital](https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr/blob/master/letsgodigital/letsgodigital.traineddata) as ocr "language"

Comment: Unfortunatelly the letsgodigital language doesn‘t work for me. Many values are wrong. :(

Comment: It works perfectly on the image you provided (well if you read docs too.)

Answer (score 0):

1. here it is a better trained [models](https://github.com/Shreeshrii/tessdata_ssd)
2. copy any of model or all inside your tesseract folder `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata`
3. configurate tesseract to use model `-l ssd`, `txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="-l ssd")`